# Show that if $G$ is not cyclic, then every element $x \neq e$ in $G$ has order $p$ or order $q$.

Tags: abstract-algebra

> Suppose $G$ is a group of order $pq$, where $p$ and $q$ are prime.
>   Show that if $G$ is not cyclic, then every element $x \neq e$ in $G$
>   has order $p$ or order $q$.

My professor posted his proof, however I am having trouble understanding one part and hopefully someone can shed some light.

Here is his proof:

Let $x \in G$ with $x \neq e$. Since $G$ is not cyclic, the order of $x$ is not $pq$. By
Lagrange’s theorem, the order of $x$, which equals the order of the subgroup
generated by $x$, divides the order of $G$, which is $pq$. Since $p$ and $q$ are prime it
follows that the order of $x$ divides $pq$. Since $x \neq e$, the order of $x$ is not equal to
one, so the order of $x$ equals $p$ or equals $q$, since are the only divisors of $pq$ other
than $1$ and $pq$

My question addresses the part where he say "Since $G$ is not cyclic, the order of $x$ is not $pq$" why is the order of $x$ not $pq$ and I'm guessing it is because $G$ is not cyclic but I'm not understanding why. In other words, how is $G$ not being cyclic not allow the element $x$ to have the order $pq$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $G$ has an element of order $|G|$, then this element will generate $G$, and hence $G$ is cyclic.

Comment: got it! makes sense now

Answer (score 3):

If the element $x$ had order $pq$, then it would generate *all* elements of the group. Hence, the group would be cyclic -generated by $x$-.

So, now, the contrapositive of that is that if the group is not cyclic, $x$ cannot have order $pq$...

Comment: thanks for the answer